# How do I launch com.android.launcher?

Tags: android, launcher

I created an app that acts as a launcher, which works as expected, but I'd like to give the user the ability to launch the native Android Launcher.

I know that the package name for the Android Launcher is `com.android.launcher`

However, when I try to get the Launch intent name from this package by calling

```
packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.launcher");
```

that comes up null.

So, I'm at a loss as to how to use the package name to launch it, and am wondering if perhaps there's some alternate way?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know that the package name for the Android Launcher is com.android.launcher

Except that may or may not be on any given device. In fact, I would expect it to be on maybe a few percent of devices. Most manufacturers replace the stock home screen with their own.

> am wondering if perhaps there's some alternate way?

Use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to find all activities that support `ACTION_MAIN` and `CATEGORY_HOME`. Remove your activity from the list. If there is only one left, launch that activity. If there is more than one left, whip up your own chooser to show the available options. That way, no matter what other home screen(s) exists, you will be able to launch it.

**UPDATE**

Given a `ResolveInfo` named `launchable`, and an `ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_HOME` template `Intent` named `i`, to launch that activity, do:

```
ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                     activity.name);

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
i.setComponent(name);

startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Commons, that's actually exactly what I'm doing (I simplified for the sake of the question). The problem is I don't know *how to launch it. All I have is the package name (which is what I meant when I said "I know... etc. etc." So, how do I transform that package name into a launchable (or lunchable) intent when the method I cite above (getLaunchIntentForPackage) returns null on the package which by process of elimination IS the home Android launcher (and on this device happens to be "com.android.launcher")?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: See update. You can see a more extended example here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot In this case, I am implementing a launcher, and so my template `Intent` is for `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`, not `CATEGORY_HOME`, and I am getting the `ResolveInfo` from a `ListView` click.